# cPanel doesn't support node version 12.16.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server, cpanel

I want to host my node api (built in node version 12.16.0) on cPanel, but available version for node in cPanel is 12.9.0 (Most recent). What should I do now ? Does it really matter, the node version ?

Answer (score 0):

Although 12.18.2 is LTS on the current date, but I think you can move ahead with 12.9 as well. It is a minor update.

In case you want to manage the version then you should use `nvm` node version manager. Using `nvm` you can manage the latest version as default on your server.

Make sure to install the latest version of Node Js before setting that as default version on your server. and you need to install `nvm` as well.

Use the following commands:

```
nvm install 12.18.2

nvm alias default v12.18.2
```

Comment: But the cPanel won't support latest version of Node.js.
The versions supported are 10.20.1, 11.15.0, 12.9.0 only.

Comment: you need to install latest version using console OR ask the hosting service to install that